# Como puedo mejorar este programa basico de python sobre entrada a Zoologico y el calcular total

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un ejercicio o programa que consiste en un ingreso a un zoológico, dependiendo de si es niño, adulto y adulto mayor se  calculará el total a pagar. Niño tiene un precio, adulto otro precio y adulto mayor otro precio.

Por ejemplo le pongo 5 personas y me sale la opción 5 veces si es adulto, niño o adulto mayor.
El tema es que lo quiero hacer un poco mas fácil, por ejemplo si van 20 niños voy a tener que hacerlo 20 veces y mi idea es hacerlo 2 veces, si se entiendo.

````
entradasPersonas=int(input("Cuanta gente viene al zoologico: "))
nino=0
adulto=0
adultom=0
b=0

d=0
e=0

for i in range(entradasPersonas):
    print("Seleccione que tipo de tarifa segun edad (opción del 1 al 3)")
    print("1-Niños")
    print("2-Adulto")
    print ("3-Adulto Mayor")
    tipo=int(input())
    if tipo == 1:
          
        nino=nino+1
        b=nino*1500
    if tipo == 2:
          
        adulto=adulto+1
        d=adulto*2500
    if tipo == 3:
          
        adultom=adultom+1
        e=adultom*1000
    
   


print("El monto total a pagar por las ",entradasPersonas  ,  " personas para entrar al Zoo $",b+d+e) ```
````

Comment: eh no, no se entiende.. cual es el problema que tenes? queres directamente poner el total por tipo?

Answer (score 1):

Tu codigo se puede simplificar mucho, se puede poner el precio en un diccionario o una tupla asignando el tipo de persona y el precio, yo lo hice con un diccionario, también nos ahorramos el ciclo `for` ya que podemos directamente preguntar cuantos niños, adultos y adultos mayores van, el código quedaría asi:

```py
entradasPersonas=int(input("Cuanta gente viene al zoologico: "))

precios = {"niños":1500,"adulto":2500,"adultoM":1000}

#print("Seleccione que tipo de tarifa segun edad (opción del 1 al 3)")
ninos = int(input("cuantos niños son?: "))
adulto = int(input("cuantos Adultos son?: "))
adultoM = int(input("cuanros Adultos Mayores son?: "))

if ninos + adulto + adultoM != entradasPersonas:
    print("los datos no coinciden")
else:    
    precio = precios['niños'] * ninos + precios['adulto'] * adulto + precios['adultoM'] * adultoM
    

    print("El monto total a pagar por las ",entradasPersonas  ,  " personas para entrar al Zoo es: $",precio)
```

Aquí hice una comparación entre el total de personas y los datos ingresados, esto para verificar, puedes omitir la primera parte donde preguntas cuantas personas van y solo quedarte con el número de personas que el usuario va ingresando, creo que el código aún se puede mejorar, pero esta es mi solución por ahora :)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo mejor que podrías hacer es utilizar una función, ya que eso te ahorraría mucho trabajo y muchos bucles:

```
def precio(nino, adulto, anciano):
    cantidad = nino+adulto+anciano
    nino = nino*1500
    adulto = adulto *2500
    anciano = anciano *1000
    total = nino + adulto + anciano
    return total, cantidad

nino = int(input("Por favor, ingrese la cantidad de niños que vendrán al zoo: \n"))
adulto = int(input("Por favor, ingrese la cantidad de adultos que vendrán al zoo: \n"))
anciano = int(input("Por favor, ingrese la cantidad de adultos mayores que vendrán al zoo: \n"))

total_Entrada, cantidad_entrada = precio(nino,adulto,anciano)
print("El monto total a pagar por las ",cantidad_entrada  ,  " personas para entrar al Zoo es: $",total_Entrada)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no preguntas la cantidad de personas por tarifa. 
Sugeriría que el algoritmo sea lo más flexible posible para la persona que va a facturar. Por ejemplo, si facturas 10 niños, pero se quedaron 2 por fuera, el sistema debería poder registrarlos sin tener que terminar el programa y volver a hacer el proceso ahora con 12.

Mi propuesta sería la siguiente (Python 3.6+):

```
tarifa = {'1':['Niño', 1500], '2':['Adulto', 2500], 
    '3':['Adulto Mayor', 1000], '4':['Facturar', '']}

for key, value in tarifa.items(): # imprime el menu
    print(f'{key} - {value[0]} ({value[1]})')

personas = 0
total = 0
while True:
    tipo = input("Seleccione una tarifa: ")
    if tipo == '4': # Opción de salida
        break
    elif tipo in tarifa:
        tipo_t = tarifa[tipo][0]
        cant = int(input(f"Cantidad entradas tipo [{tipo_t}]: "))
        subtot = cant * tarifa[tipo][1]
        print(f" > Agregado: {tipo_t} x {cant} -> {subtot}")
        personas += cant
        total += subtot
    else:
        print("Esta tarifa no existe")
        
print(f"El monto total para {personas} personas es: {total}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer varias cosas para mejorarlo, todo depende de lo que necesites posteriormente con tu código.
En primer lugar, no necesitas preguntar cuantas personas van a entrar al zoo, puesto que ya te lo van a decir introduciendo individualmente las edades.

Por otro lado, si no necesitas guardar la cantidad de `niños`, `adultos` y `adultos mayores` que entran y únicamente necesitas el precio total a pagar, puedes hacer solo una pregunta en un ciclo `for`:

```
precios = {"niños": 1500, "adultos": 2500, "adultos mayores": 1000}

personas, precio = 0, 0
for edad in precios:
    n = int(input(f"¿cuántos {edad} son?: "))
    personas += n
    precio += n * precios[edad]

print(f'El monto total a pagar por las {personas} personas para entrar al Zoo es: ${precio}')
```

Para una entrada de:

```
¿cuántos niños son?: 3
¿cuántos adultos son?: 1
¿cuántos adultos mayores son?: 5
```

Devolvería:

```
El monto total a pagar por las 9 personas para entrar al Zoo es: $12000
```

Como puedes ver, para cada edad pide un número y aprovecha el bucle para agregarlo a la variable `personas`, y a su vez calcula el precio parcial y lo suma a `precio`.

Cuando termina el bucle devuelve el total de personas y el total a pagar. La desventaja de esta manera es que no puedes consultar la cantidad de `niños` (y por lo tanto el precio parcial que pagaron), y lo mismo para `adultos` y `adultos mayores`. Pero si no lo vas a necesitar esta manera te puede servir.

En caso de querer acceder a esos datos más adelante en tu código, puedes aprovechar y almacenarlas en el diccionario inicial a medida que las vas pidiendo:

```
datos = {'niños': {'precio': 1500},
         'adultos': {'precio': 2500},
         'adultos mayores': {'precio': 1000}}

personas, precio_total = 0, 0
for edad in datos:
    n = int(input(f"¿cuántos {edad} son?: "))
    personas += n
    precio_total += n * datos[edad]['precio']
    datos[edad]['cantidad'] = n

print(f'El monto total a pagar por las {personas} personas para entrar al Zoo es: ${precio_total}')
```

En este caso para la misma entrada de datos anterior devolvería:

```
El monto total a pagar por las 9 personas para entrar al Zoo es: $12000
Han entrado un total de:
    -3 niños, por $4500
    -1 adultos, por $2500
    -5 adultos mayores, por $5000
```

Como ves, ahora puedes acceder a todos los datos, ya que el diccionario `datos` ha quedado de esta manera:

```
{'niños': {'precio': 1500, 
           'cantidad': 3}, 
 'adultos': {'precio': 2500, 
             'cantidad': 1}, 
 'adultos mayores': {'precio': 1000, 
                     'cantidad': 5}}
```